# swift Balloons.playground cannot be open

Tags: ios, swift

I have download the Balloons.playground from here, https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=9

Balloons.playground is demo on WWDC 2014 .

But it can not be open .

It says:
Playgrounds targeting OS X are not supported in this version of Xcode. [I use the latest Xcode version . 6.0.1 , and mac os version is OS X Yosemite 10.10 the latest too.]

Sorry, I can't post images right now ,[You need at least 10 reputation to post images] ^0^

I don't know how to fix this to open that file. I right click the file and select "Show Package Contents." , A lot of files here , a lot of swift files, so I want to create a new playground file and copy them, but there are more than ten swift files with sections, I do not what the section means here.

So I want to open that playground file and run it.

Answer (score 1):

You are running the Yosemite preview. You need to download Xcode 6.1 from the Developer Site to use the Mac OS X playground. The current Xcode 6 works only with iOS playgrounds.